# Java nested generic class with only one type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on a project that has a generic stream interface that provides values of a type:

```
interface Stream<T> {
  T get();  // returns the next value in the stream
}
```

I have one implementation that provides single values simply from a file or whatever.  It looks like this:

```
class SimpleStream<T> implements Stream<T> {
  // ...
}
```

I would also like to have another implementation that provides pairs of values (say, to provide the next two values for each call to get()).  So I define a small Pair class:

```
class Pair<T> {
  public final T first, second;

  public Pair(T first, T second) {
    this.first = first; this.second = second;
}
```

and now I would like to define a second implementation of the Stream interface that only works with Pair classes, like this:

```
// Doesn't compile
class PairStream<Pair<T>> implements Stream<Pair<T>> {
  // ...
}
```

This does not compile, however.

I could do this:

```
class PairStream<U extends Pair<T>, T> implements Stream<U> {
  // ...
}
```

but is there any more elegant way?  Is this the "right" way to do this?

Comment: You left out a `>` in the `class PairStream<Pair<T>> implements Stream<Pair<T>` line.

Comment: typo here: Stream<Pair<T> ?

Comment: I fixed the typo; it was not actually part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic type parameter `Pair<T>` is not valid; you just need to declare `<T>` and use it when implementing the interface.

```
//         Just <T> here;          Added missing (2nd) '>'
class PairStream<T> implements Stream<Pair<T>> {
    public Pair<T> get() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is

```
class PairStream<T> implements Stream<Pair<T>> {
  // ...
}
```

This might work too:

```
class PairStream<U extends Pair<T>> implements Stream<U> {
    // ...
}
```